# USB detection code  for android device is crashing

Tags: java, android, usb

I have written a small code for usb detection for android device but its crashing while I connect the device cable to CPU of my computer

Here is my code

```
public class IntentReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        if(intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_UMS_CONNECTED))

        {

            Toast.makeText(context, "mounted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Log.i("ANDROID DEVICE IS","CONNECTED");
            System.out.println(" ANDROID DEVICE IS CONNECTED");
            // Intent myStarterIntent = new Intent(context, CarHome.class);
            //   myStarterIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            //   context.startActivity(myStarterIntent);
        }

        else if(intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_UMS_DISCONNECTED)){

            Toast.makeText(context, "Unmounted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Log.i("ANDROID DEVICE IS","DISCONNECTED");  
            System.out.println(" ANDROID DEVICE IS NOT CONNECTED");
        }
    }

}
```

Manifest file is here

```
<receiver android:name=".IntentReceiver">
    <intent-filter>
      <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_UMS_CONNECTED" />
      <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_UMS_DISCONNECTED" />
      <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Logcat showing these errors

```
05-25 15:30:08.350: E/AndroidRuntime(3457):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:1785)
05-25 15:30:08.350: E/AndroidRuntime(3457):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2400(ActivityThread.java:121)
05-25 15:30:08.350: E/AndroidRuntime(3457):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:993)
05-25 15:30:08.350: E/AndroidRuntime(3457):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-25 15:30:08.350: E/AndroidRuntime(3457):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
05-25 15:30:08.350: E/AndroidRuntime(3457):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3701)
05-25 15:30:08.350: E/AndroidRuntime(3457):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-25 15:30:08.350: E/AndroidRuntime(3457):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
05-25 15:30:08.350: E/AndroidRuntime(3457):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866)
05-25 15:30:08.350: E/AndroidRuntime(3457):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:624)
05-25 15:30:08.350: E/AndroidRuntime(3457):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-25 15:30:08.350: E/AndroidRuntime(3457): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.kk88655.hello.IntentReceiver in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.kk88655.hello-2.apk]
05-25 15:30:08.350: E/AndroidRuntime(3457):     at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:240)
05-25 15:30:08.350: E/AndroidRuntime(3457):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:551)
05-25 15:30:08.350: E/AndroidRuntime(3457):     at  java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
```

Latest logcat messages

```
05-25 17:51:32.878: E/AndroidRuntime(5602): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-25 17:51:32.878: E/AndroidRuntime(5602): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate receiver com.kk88655.hello.IntentReceiver: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.kk88655.hello.IntentReceiver in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.kk88655.hello-1.apk]
05-25 17:51:32.878: E/AndroidRuntime(5602):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:1785)
05-25 17:51:32.878: E/AndroidRuntime(5602):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2400(ActivityThread.java:121)
05-25 17:51:32.878: E/AndroidRuntime(5602):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:993)
05-25 17:51:32.878: E/AndroidRuntime(5602):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-25 17:51:32.878: E/AndroidRuntime(5602):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
05-25 17:51:32.878: E/AndroidRuntime(5602):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3701)
05-25 17:51:32.878: E/AndroidRuntime(5602):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-25 17:51:32.878: E/AndroidRuntime(5602):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
05-25 17:51:32.878: E/AndroidRuntime(5602):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866)
05-25 17:51:32.878: E/AndroidRuntime(5602):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:624)
05-25 17:51:32.878: E/AndroidRuntime(5602):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-25 17:51:32.878: E/AndroidRuntime(5602): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.kk88655.hello.IntentReceiver in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.kk88655.hello-1.apk]
05-25 17:51:32.878: E/AndroidRuntime(5602):     at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:240)
05-25 17:51:32.878: E/AndroidRuntime(5602):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:551)
05-25 17:51:32.878: E/AndroidRuntime(5602):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
05-25 17:51:32.878: E/AndroidRuntime(5602):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:1776)
05-25 17:51:32.878: E/AndroidRuntime(5602):     ... 10 more
05-25 17:51:32.878: W/ActivityManager(238):   Force finishing activity com.kk88655.hello/.CarHome
```

Comment: I found this [post][1] useful if you still have a problem.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7142987/media-mounted-broadcast-not-being-recieved

Comment: @Hannes, Thanks for the link, the issue was solved already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should read the docs:

> ACTION_UMS_CONNECTED
>
> This constant is **deprecated**. replaced by
>   `android.os.storage.StorageEventListener`
>
> Broadcast Action: The device has entered USB Mass Storage mode. This
>   is **used mainly for the USB Settings panel. Apps should listen for
>   ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED and ACTION_MEDIA_UNMOUNTED broadcasts** to be
>   notified when the SD card file system is mounted or unmounted

---

Against your `ClassNotFoundException`:

In your manifest, you prefixed the class-name of your BoradcastReceiver with a period, which  is a shortcut. It will take the package-name you specified in your `<manifest>`-tags `package`-attribute and add the given class-name to it.

So, you should make sure that your fully qualified class-path is `com.kk88655.hello.IntentReceiver`, because it seems that you renamed the `hello`-package to `hello2` (as seen in the logcat: `/data/app/com.kk88655.hello-2.apk`).

---

A similar question has already been asked here: [Android Broadcast Receiver Error: Class not found exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3558977/android-broadcast-receiver-error-class-not-found-exception) with no accepted or up-voted answer so far.

Another idea would be to specify the fully-qualified package-name in the `<receiver>`-tags `android:name`-attribute, as suggested here: [Unable to instantiate receiver in BroadcastReceiver SMS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4619049/unable-to-instantiate-receiver-in-broadcastreceiver-sms)

Another explanation might be an update-issue with your older application-version as discussed here: [ClassNotFoundException error reports when upgrading Android app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5769534/classnotfoundexception-error-reports-when-upgrading-android-app) Reading this question, it also might be an App2SD problem.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the Information , I tried with your suggestion but  its not working for me

Comment: Error? Behavior? Please be more specific.

Comment: Can you post the full stacktrace? It should start with something like `java.lang.XXX-Exception: [Problem]`

Comment: I posted the latest logcat messages in my question

Comment: I did some more research and updated my answer. Please check if this helps you. Otherwise, I suppose this is an Android Bug.